# mvn verify downloads jars from artifactory but Eclipse Maven -> Update project does not work

Tags: eclipse, maven, ssl, m2eclipse

When I checkout project from git repository, I get error saying non-resolvable parent pom. It manages to checkout the src files but does not download the maven dependencies and other jar files and does not produce a valid maven project. I also get "cannot be resolved to a type" errors in bunch of files. 
This is the error I see in the .lastUpdated file on the parent project in .m2 repository .

> "sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target"

But if I go and run mvn verify from command line, it downloads all jar files. And now when i do maven update project from eclipse, all errors are gone.

The artifactory has a self-signed ssl certificate and I have followed the steps for this.

I have also set the MAVEN_OPTS with truststore location and password.

What I don't get is why it is connecting from commandline and not from eclipse.

Comment: Simple answer. These are completely two different things. Eclipse is not the command line and vice versa.

Comment: How do I get it working on eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved similar issue in 3 different ways. Select only one of them:

1. Import .cer certificate into the installed jdk cacert file. Be sure JAVA_HOME environment variable references to this jdk and Eclipse uses the same jdk. Then restart Eclipse.
2. Import .cer certificate into the Eclipse jdk plugin. Path to this plugin can be found in eclipse.ini file as `-vm` argument (for example, in my env for Eclipse 2021-09 (4.21.0) it is plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_16.0.2.v20210721-1149/jre/bin). Find there cacert file and import certificate into. Then restart Eclipse.
3. Provide truststore and its password in eclipse.ini file (in the Eclipse home) after -vmargs:

`-vmargs`

`-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="C:/certificates/cert.jks"`

`-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=***`